# linux kill whole pipe on exist of script

Tags: php, linux, bash, pipe

```
tail -n 1 -f /tmp/remoteinput | php ./myscript.php conf.conf
```

I run the above command to have myscript accept redirected input. This bit is working.

The issue I am facing is when myscript.php finishes execution it exit's however the
pipe is still left open. I think tail is still lingering.

What I want to archive is when myscript.php exits to have the whole pipe killed

Answer (score 0):

Use tail without `-f` parameter. `-f` makes it continuing to listen, so command never dies and pipe is never closed.

> ```
>    -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
>           output appended data as the file grows; -f, --follow, and --follow=descriptor are equivalent
> ```

Comment: I need the f option as I will continually send input not just the once.

Comment: So you have to think about refactoring your solution. Ideally your script should never close its input pipe to accept content from `tailing`. It would make both `tail -f` and `myscript.php` never stop.